# Setting different title and meta title for a page

Tags: magento2, frontend, meta

I'm creating a simple page in my Magento 2 instance.
in the controller for that page I'm trying to set a title for the page and a meta title that should be different.
But I'm not able to do that.
My layout file for the action is almost empty:

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    </body>

</page>
```

and my controller action looks like this:

```
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Controller\[Entity];

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set('Something');
    }
}
```

The result is this:

[image]

But the meta title is the same as the title (`Something`).
Changing the line in the controller:

```
$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set('Something');
```

to

```
$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set('Something else');
```

results in the title (H1 tag) and the meta title changing to `something else`.

How can I set a different meta title and a title (h1 tag) to a page

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is how I managed to get different Meta Title and Page Heading. I have below code In my block class:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $pageConfig,
    $data = array()
) {
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig; 
    $this->_pageConfig = $pageConfig;   

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

 /**
 * Prepare global layout
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->_pageConfig->addBodyClass('advance-sitemap');

    if($this->getSeoTitle())
        $this->_pageConfig->getTitle()->set('Meta Title');

    if($this->getMetaKeywords())        
        $this->_pageConfig->setKeywords('Meta Keywords');

    if($this->getMetaDescription())         
        $this->_pageConfig->setDescription('Meta Description');

    $pageMainTitle = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
    if ($pageMainTitle) {
        $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle('Page Heading Title');
    }

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

**[EDIT by OP]**
You can set the page title from the controller also, like this:

```
$resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
$pageMainTitle = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
if ($pageMainTitle && $pageMainTitle instanceof \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title) {
    $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle('Page title here');
}
//rest of the code here.
```

Comment: I don't know if setting the page title from a content block is the best idea, but your answer got me in the right direction. Setting the page title on the `page.main.title` block works in controllers also. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing this. Would you mind to share the whole code in your answer (Is it Main.php?; ..layout.xml; template.phtml) you have used for this? I somehow can not reproduce/I do not see any result in my case. That would be super-awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Just tried myself for a new custom extension, it works for me :

```
public function execute() {
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    // Handling page title
    $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title')->setPageTitle('Page title here');
    // Handling meta_title, meta_description and meta_keywords
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set("Title");
    $resultPage->getConfig()->setDescription("Description");
    $resultPage->getConfig()->setKeywords("Key Words");
    return $resultPage;
}
```

It shoud do the job !

Comment: where did u add this?

Comment: In the execute() method of my Action Controller

Answer (score 0):

What about using:

```
$resultPage->getConfig()->getMetadata()->setMetadata('title', 'Something else');
```

for meta title.

Comment: it doesn't work. `->getMetadata()` returns an array so I cannot call `setMetadata` on the result. And removing `getMetadata` from the line just results in an error `Object of class Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title could not be converted to string`.

Comment: by using setMetadata(), you can set custom meta property like $resultPage->getConfig()->getMetadata()->setMetadata('meta_title', 'Something else');

Comment: @JaiminParikh. You cannot chain the 2 calls `getMetadata()->setMetadata` because `getMetadata` returns an array and you cannot call a method from an array. I explained this in the comment above. But I tried with  `$resultPage->getConfig()->setMetadata('meta_title', 'Something else');` and there is no change. I think this does not work because there is no `<meta name="title"...` rendered in the page. the title renders as `<title>...</title>`

Comment: @Marius yes i am wrong at that. but by using $resultPage->getConfig()->setMetadata('meta_title', 'Something else'); , t will create new meta tag which name is "meta_title" and it will be no useful.

Answer (score 0):

For the meta title you have to use the

`\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config::setMetaTitle($title)`

Mean

```
 $pageConfig->setMetaTitle('Meta title value')
```

where `$pageConfig` is object of `\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config`.

```
  $resultPage->getConfig()->setMetaTitle($title);
```

if you use `$pageConfig->getTitle()->set(" My Title")` then vale set for  both meta title and `<title>` field

```
<meta name="title" content="My Title"/>

<title>My Title</title>
```

If you use

```
$pageConfig->getTitle()->set(" My Title");
$pageConfig->setMetaTitle('Meta title value');
```

**The expected result  will be:**

```
<meta name="title" content="My Title"/>

<title>Meta title value</title>
```