# Setting Meta Title with Redirect

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, meta-title

I've been trying to set the meta title of a product listing page when an action is executed. I found [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125358/setting-different-title-and-meta-title-for-a-page) post on Magento2 StackExchange and tried to replicate in my Controller:

```
<?php
    namespace TreyBake\Garage\Controller\Index;

    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

    class Search extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {        
        protected $resultPageFactory;
        protected $_pageConfig;

        public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $pageConfig
        )
        {
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            $this->_pageConfig = $pageConfig;

            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        protected function _prepareLayout()
        {
            $this->_pageConfig->getTitle()->set('foo');
            $pmt = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
            $pmt->setPageTitle('bar');

            return parent::_prepareLayout();
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            # my controller exec code

            $rpf = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $pmt = $rpf->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
            $pmt->setPageTitle('foobar');

            # etc.
        }
    }
```

Disabling one at a time makes no change, and both uncommented has no affect. What am I doing wrong and how can I override the meta title (`<title>`) for product listing pages using `$_GET` params (though, really, if I know how to set the meta title correctly, I can fill in the blanks with $_GET)?

**Update:**

I think I know why this is so troublesome, the last line in the `execute()` method is this:

```
$this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl);
```

doing a log of this shows the `$backUrl` to equate to:

> http://site.development/wheel-tyres/tyres.html?find=aprilia-af-1-futura-1990-4730&sid=cbFktM0OTy

So I don't think I can `return $resultPageFactory` as, it's redirected before it's returned.

My Edited Question: **How do I set the meta title with redirect?**

**Another Update**

I tried using `getResponse()` to set the data, as I did some logging and it doesn't seem I can use it:

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP. '/var/log/dev.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info(
    print_r(
        get_class_methods($this->getResponse),
        true
    )
);
```

This led me to three functions of interest:

- `getHeaders()`
- `getMetaData()`
- `setMetaData()`

I then logged the get* functions and `getMetaData()` was empty, getHeaders had data, but I overlooked what it might mean, headers are the HTTP headers (duh).

I then used `setMetaData('title', 'foo')` and logged `getMetaData` after that and huzzah, my data is there - however, the title for the page remains the same.. again, I'm guessing because of the redirect.

Comment: Is this issue been resolved already?

Comment: @magefms not yet - though haven't tried any of the below solutions - going to try implementing now :)

Comment: can you update your code also ? you're right that getresponse could be the reason why your code is not working.

Comment: @magefms I've added the line I think crucial - everything else works, but I think the redirect is probably stopping the setting of meta title

Comment: yeah , possibly

Comment: I think it's not doable unless you omit the redirect. what's the purpose of the response redirect? have you tried using session?

Comment: @magefms it's for the Amasty Finder plugin, so I don't really want to rewrite the Amasty plugin for sessions :/

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code:

```
 public function execute()
        {
            # my controller exec code

            $rpf = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $pmt = $rpf->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('foobar'));;
        }
```

Comment: returned error of: `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setTitle() on boolean` :s

Answer (score 1):

This code is working for me, in your **execute()** function you have to use this code

```
/**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set('foobar');
        return $resultPage;
    }
```

I hope it will work for you

Comment: see edit about use of return :)

Answer (score 1):

Try **`prepend(__("Title"));`**

```
public function execute()
    {
        $rpf = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
        $rpf->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__(" foobar"));
        return $rpf;
    }
```

or

```
public function execute()
{
    $rpf = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
    $rpf->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
    $rpf->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__(" foobar"));
    return $rpf;
}
```

or

```
public function execute()
{
    $rpf = $this->resultPageFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
    $rpf->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
    $rpf->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__(" foobar"));
    return $rpf;
}
```

To make sure the given solution above will work, don't forget to add this before your class :

> **`use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;`**

Comment: I should note: the last line in my current controller is: `$this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl);` so I don't think I can use return here

Comment: lemme update question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your category page title to something comes from $_GET like this:

[image]

You should create a plugin for **Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View**

Detail steps are below:

> 1. app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View">
        <plugin name="training_catalog_product_list" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Category\View"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> 2. app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Catalog/Controller/Category/View.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Controller\Category;


class View
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page) {

            $title = $subject->getRequest()->getParam('test', false);
            if ($title) {
                $result->getConfig()->getTitle()->set($title);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Hope this will solve your issue. Let me know if you have any question

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom event to set product title dynamic or by **$_GET** url
Please check below steps for more information.

In your custom module please create **event.xml** file

**/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_load_after">
        <observer name="dynamic_title_generator" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AfterProductLoad" />
    </event> 
</config>
```

Add below code in your Observer

**/app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/AfterProductLoad.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class AfterProductLoad implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ){
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $metaTitle = $observer->getRequest()->getParam('test', false);

        //You can set any dynamic title from here as well.
        if ($metaTitle) {
            $product->setMetaTitle($metaTitle);
            $product->setIsMetaApplied(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to store the title you need in the session before calling the redirect and reuse it in a plugin hooked in before the `set()` method in `Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title` 
I assume you wan't to change the page title everywhere - otherwise another appropriate pluggable method should be used. For example if you want to overwrite only the HTML title, you might better plug in in `Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer` after the method `renderTitle()`, that should also work. Where to plug in depends on your specific requierements.

Example code:

**1. add session object in your controller and store title**

```
 [...]
protected $_catalogSession;
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $pageConfig,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession
)
[...]
public function execute()
{
    [...]
    $this->_catalogSession->setMyTitle("My Title");
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl);
}
```

**2. add plugin in di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title">
        <plugin name="YourModule_Page_Plugin" type="YourNamespace\YourModule\Plugin\TitlePlugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
    </type>
</config>
```

**3. create plugin TitlePlugin.php**

```
class TitlePlugin{

    protected $_catalogSession;

    public function __construct( 
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession
        ){
            $this->_catalogSession = $catalogSession;
    }

    public function beforeSet(\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title $titleObject, string $title)
    {
        //set the parameter to true, to use the title only once (i.e. the call from the redirect in previous controller)
        //this could be a problem if setTitle() is called more than once in your target page (for whatever reason)
        $mytitle = $this->_catalogSession->getMyTitle(true);
        if (!empty($mytitle)){
            $title = $mytitle;
        }

        return $title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if this helps you or if you need further support.